# Has JPL been affected by the November 2018 California wildfires?

Tags: deep-space-network, uncrewed-spaceflight, facility

The [Deep Space Network Now](https://eyes.nasa.gov/dsn/dsn.html) page shows no activity at all.  Two hours ago, there was only testing on two of the Madrid dishes (so it's more than a faulty webpage).  I've never seen anything like it before.

During the past week, there have been two massive wildfires in California.  The fact that the Canberra and Madrid sites are also down suggest that the problem is not limited to Goldstone, but affects JPL in Pasadena.

Does anyone have any information on this condition?  Has JPL been affected by the wildfires?

Comment: Canberra is back up!  Yeah!

Comment: at `02:00` UTC there is only a bit of setup/teardown https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkWJF.png I would be surprised if each DSN site couldn't execute their pre-planned, scheduled, and approved communication sequences on their own, even if LA county fell into the ocean or was submerged in lava Hollywood style.

Comment: `02:09` Canberra getting ready for uplink https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2aEl.png wow I wonder why all of DSN would "go dark" for hours. Scheduled, system-wide software updates?

Comment: Canberra and Goldstone, now 2 dishes up each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't appear so. Their home page features a story on imaging the fires from space (https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/news.php?feature=7278)

Looking at the image featured in that story, JPL is near the right side of the picture (northeast of Glendale).

Employees could be severely impacted, of course.

[image]